из-за чего ошибка *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
при вводе строки "A RozA upala Na lapu AzoR" выдаёт ошибку *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated.
Из-за чего это может происходить?
Вот код:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s, p, s2;
    getline(cin,s);

    int i = 0, n = s.length(),k = 0, sch = 0;

    k = s.length() - 1;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        s2[sch] = s[k];
        k--;
        sch++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(s[i] == s2[i]){
            p = "Yes";
        }
        else{
            p = "No";
        }
    }
    cout << p;

    return 0;
}


s2 изначально пустая строка. Таким образом, присваивание
s2[sch] = s[k];

запихивает данные куда-то*, куда нельзя, и вполне может портить стек...
Добавьте строку
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    assert(sch < s2.length());
    s2[sch] = s[k];

и убедитесь сами :)
Если вы так странно проверяете строку на палиндромность, то хотя бы добавьте что-то вроде s2=s или как-то иначе инициализируйте ее.
Но проще проверять палиндромность иначе...
Например, если уж обращать строку и тратить память - то
string s, s2;
getline(cin,s);
s2 = s;
reverse(s2.begin(),s2.end());
cout << ((s == s2) ? "Yes" : "No");

Не тратить память и время -
string s;
bool p = true;
getline(cin,s);
for(int i = 0, j = s.size() - 1; i < j; ++i, --j)
    if (s[i] != s[j]) { p = false; break; }
cout << (p ? "Yes" : "No");

или то же через итераторы...

Спасибо! Но странно, что при вводе других строк ошибки не было

Undefined Behavior на то и Undefined. Вы, когда на красный свет дорогу перебегаете, тоже не каждый раз в больницу попадаете...

Эта строка и должна быть по условию задачи

https://statement.bacs.cs.istu.ru/statement/get/CjRiYWNzL3Byb2JsZW0vc2Nob29sXzdfMTVfNS9zdGF0ZW1lbnQvdmVyc2lvbnMvQy9odG1sEgYKBAB7MkQ/bacs/N9SZbsCxbHXj5DjElfBqH3hotF3Fh2WEVXwbdq0A87C9Z4wdilObcUJ9JeAXaHMHbotDWAEKadFUQWKAUhcrapeAWQ5RUe5SJ0pvExeXhfb7o0h8-JyMHqHWDFANZiRjKUW1iGhrwtb3yh7FN7rKkdO54o2k0RFRkNm3FgHxUEzL9vybCtbGI9xglUdwYxNMKkHKz_m1IpvYB52wmuuG0p20AZhrrBUKUGqCq2fweZ1tjhAzrMbsTIJZYfWA3gcXMfeqf0w5sALXup2X7sWUI_OzLMOVdKXHK20vwPKz980m2Vg1lmS3vIBdixKSmSEl0KTgpYxWHLoG6XKV3pxVjA/problem.html
